# getting errors everytime I open or close a file in Atom Editor

Tags: typeerror, atom-editor

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FEvH.jpg)

I am getting errors every time I open or close a new/existing file in Atom-Editor.
I tried to find on the link provided by the editor but no use.
Is there any way to fix this issue?!

Comment: I think this issue still remains till date.https://github.com/awaw00/autoclose/issues/24

Comment: Someone happened to post a fix for this but it's not merged into master yet.https://github.com/awaw00/autoclose/pull/16/commits/4f3fe85121d6eceff49cff3cd85d19b2aa84439f#